# Accessibility - screen reader read the same aria label multiple times

Tags: angularjs, html, accessibility, angular-material

I'm using this code for indication if a button is collapsed or not:

```
<!--show more start-->
<div class="expand-section-button compensate-padding-left"
     ng-if="ctrl.isShowMore(ctrl.facetGroup)"
     (click)="ctrl.toggleMoreFacets(ctrl.facetGroup)"
     aria-label="{{::ctrl.facetGroup.name}}">

    <md-button class="button-as-link link-alt-color zero-margin"
               aria-label="{{'facets.facet.facet_'+ ctrl.facetGroup.name | translate}}">

            <span class="bold-text"
                  translate="nui.facets.showmore"
                  translate-attr-title="nui.facets.showmore">
            </span>

    </md-button>

</div>
<!--show more end-->



<div ng-init="messageAdded = 'open' ; 
          messageRemoved = 'close' "
          class="accessible-only"
          aria-label="{{ctrl.isShowMore(ctrl.facetGroup) ? messageAdded :   messageRemoved}}"
          aria-live="assertive" >{{ctrl.isShowMore(ctrl.facetGroup) ? messageAdded : messageRemoved}} </div>
```

From some reason the screen reader (NVDA) read it 4 times.
Why?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML generated by that code? That's what the screenreader will be using.

Comment: @string I edited my question with the html code

Comment: The content inside the div start/end tags should just be a text string, or more HTML. Maybe validate your HTML before trying again with NVDA.